# Dell Latitude E5440 Graphics bug on Windows 11

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, windows-11

At this point, it has been more than 24 hours since I try to fix this problem on my own.
My external monitor worked just fine till I turned off my laptop yesterday. Since then, I can't get the external monitor to be detected in Windows 11. Tried reinstalling both Integrated and Dedicated GPU drivers. Nothing helped.

I had this issue before but reinstalling the graphics drivers always did the trick. Now that "fix" doesn't work anymore as well. Basically Windows 11 doesn't detect my external monitor at all although it is plugged in correctly into the HDMI port.

Is there any driver or settings related to the communication between the Dedicated and Integrated GPU? I know that the HDMI port works through the Integrated GPU to use the Dedicated GPU on the external monitor. I suspect there is an issue there but at this point, I am stuck.

Comment: I also suspect the culprit is Windows Updates again, breaking stuff instead of fixing, as usual.

Comment: @Ramhound Intel Corporation - Display - 10/29/2018 12:00:00 AM - 20.19.15.5063

Comment: @Ramhound not 100% sure. It must have been installed when I turned off the PC. The time and date is exactly to when the problem started. Just trying to find what was the previous version to this so I can downgrade.

Comment: @Ramhound I had no issues till this version was installed. Yes. The CPU is an I5 4300U.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the suggestion! A quick question as I try to install the drivers. In some cases, the order is also important as one picks configs from the other. Which one would you suggest to be installed firstly? The integrated or the Dedicated?

Comment: @Ramhound I have to install both. The Dedicated GPU works through the Integrated GPU. I can't even Win + P to select the external monitor if I don't have the Inegrated GPU installed. The HDMI communicates with the Dedicated GPU through the Integrated GPU.

Comment: @Ramhound I found the problem. Something messed up with my BIOS. I have no idea how that happend. I have not entered in the settings in months. I downloaded the latest BIOS update (which I already had installed) and reinstalled it. Fixed the issue.